# sql parametrized query using LIKE

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, prepared-statement

I have tried to pass a parameter to quert but it doesn't work. What is the best way to do it? I do not want to concatenate strings. Here is my query:

```
string cmd = @"
SELECT
    *
FROM
    TABLE
WHERE 
    p.PromptTypeID = pt.ID 
    AND p.PromptDomainID = pd.ID 
    AND p.LanguageID = pl.ID 
    AND p.VoiceID = pv.ID 
    AND p.Active='Y'
    AND PromptText LIKE ?              
ORDER BY 
    p.ID DESC";

using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
            {
                command.CommandText = cmd;
                command.Transaction = transac;
                command.Connection = cnn;
                command.Parameters.Add("?", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = "%" + text + "%";
                using (SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
                {
                    adp.Fill(dt);                        
                }
            }
```

I couldn't pass the value with LIKE operator. I have also tried using @text instead of "?" but it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

**By the way it gives Incorrect syntax near '?' SqlException**

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: Looks like you're missing the text apostrophe in the SQL at the like value, at least. Should properly be a part of your parameter value.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Incorrect syntax near '?'

Comment: Take the help of this tutorial http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter

Comment: Please do not use "it doesn't work". Always write specific error you are getting. You need to write what exactly is happening when you use `@text` and also post the code with @text.

Comment: SQL Parameters should begin with `@` and an alphabet. Like `@where`.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the `?` with some SQL variable and change your `command.Parameters.Add` like below

```
PromptText LIKE %@Text%

cmd.Parameters.Add("@Text", varYourtext);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
AND PromptText LIKE @text
```

and

```
command.Parameters.Add("@text"...
```

Answer (score 0):

I have finally found the solution. When I use ".... LIKE %@text%" and passing the parameter with `command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@text", text));` it gives Incorrect syntax near '@text' exception.

But..

I used ".... LIKE @text" and passing the parameter with `command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@text", "%"+text+"%"));` it works.

Answer (score -3):

You can just use string concatenation.

```
cmd = cmd.Replace("?","'%" + text + "%'");
```

Comment: Which would completely negate the point of parameters. See Naveen's answer below (Essentially the same as Joe's but more complete and elegant relative to the OP's question).

Comment: It works but it contravene's the OP's requirements and is entirely the wrong way to go about it. One of the major points of parameterizing queries is to reduce the likelihood of SQL injection attacks but by circumventing the parameters you lose that. Just because it works does not make it a valid solution.

Comment: @StevePettifer, [SQL parameters not always protects you from sql-injection](http://taylorza.blogspot.ru/2009/04/sql-injection-are-parameterized-queries.html).

Comment: No they don't but they are a good start and what the OP wanted. Your answer is still invalid. Also check what I said: "reduce the likelihood of SQL injection attacks" not "they completely stop SQL injection attacks"